# Create custom resource with go Kubernetes client

Tags: go, kubernetes

I want to deploy a custom resource based on an already deployed CRD using the go Kubernetes client. Based on the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client?utm_source=godoc#Client) of the client I adapted the example to look like this:

```
u := &unstructured.Unstructured{}
u.Object = map[string]interface{}{
    "metadata": map[string]interface{}{
        "name": task.Name,
    },
    "spec": map[string]interface{}{
        "steps": []interface{}{
            map[string]interface{}{
                "image": "ubuntu",
                "name":  "hello",
                "command": []interface{}{
                    "echo",
                },
                "args": []interface{}{
                    "Hello World!",
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
u.SetGroupVersionKind(schema.GroupVersionKind{
    Group:   "tekton.dev",
    Version: "v1beta1",
    Kind:    "Task",
})

err := c.Create(context.Background(), u)
if err != nil {
    logger.Error("Error creating TektonTask!", "ERR", err)
} else {
    logger.Info("Created TektonTask.", "Task", u)
}
```

When I try to execute the code I don't get a feedback from the logger.Error but a panic with:

```
runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 12
```

Everything is running inside a http request handling but because I used that with other (non crd based) resources already I would assume that this is not the issue.
When expanding logging I saw that everything works until the creation of the resource with the line

```
err := c.Create(context.Background(), u)
```

Comment: Check you may haven’t initialized **k8sClient**, so it’s nil, and calling **k8sClient.Get()** ultimately results in a nil pointer dereference. Refer to [clientcmd](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd) doc to get a client to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I forgot to initialise the client with

```
c, err := client.New(config.GetConfigOrDie(), client.Options{})
```